# WPF is there a way to copy a MediaElement in c# (clone)

Tags: wpf, c#-4.0

is there a way to copy a MediaElement in c# (clone) ? 
Thank you
Wally

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only 2 ways I can think of are:

1. Make a custom Clone method. That is a lot of work and might not be possible because of the private data that you can't reach.
2. Serialize the MediaElement using a (Xaml)serializer and then deserialize.

Disclaimer: I haven't tried either of them.

Question: why would you want to Clone a MediaElement?

**EDIT** A better way of duplicating the same video might be by using the VisualBrush. Simply apply a VisualBrush that points to the MediaElement to a Rectangle. No need to copy the video or clone the MediaElement.

Comment: I tried serializing but it fails with an exception, I want to copy the video because I need to show it in the screen 4 times at the same time and reading it from disk is a performance problem.